# How to share username+password between 2 server?

Tags: php, apache, erlang, comet

I need to create for my blog in PHP, a chat like facebook-chat in erlang.

But I don't know how to share the username+password between APACHE and Ejabberd.

How do I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Store the username and password in a Mysql Database. PHP can access Mysql easily. I don't know much about Ejabbert, but from [this article here](https://support.process-one.net/doc/display/MESSENGER/Using+ejabberd+with+MySQL+native+driver) it looks like you can access Mysql from Ejabbert. Good luck.